# TFS Build DLLs and PDBs don't match

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, nuget, debug-symbols

We are using TFS 2012 to build our solution. Once this is done I use the build output to create some NuGet packages which I publish internally. I have just started building these packages with symbols as well so that I can publish these NuGet symbols packages to our internal Symbols Server.

However I am having trouble publishing the symbols packages to the Symbols Server. The reason is that the DLLs and PDBs don't match. I used [ChkMatch](http://www.debuginfo.com/tools/chkmatch.html) and indeed the **age property** is different on the DLLs and PDBs that sit in the TFS Dropfolder Release directory. If I grab the PDB files instead from the obj folder in the actual build directories then they match.

Now I believe that the age property is getting incremented because my Build Process Template has the property "Source and Symbol Server Settings > Index Sources" set to True.

1. Is it correct to just set this property for **false**?
2. Will there be any unforeseen consequences?
3. If I am using NuGet to publish my symbols can I just ignore an Source and Symbol Server Settings in the build process template?

Comment: are any of your PDB's under source control?

Comment: No, our bin and obj folders are not checked into TFS.

Comment: If you turn off indexing then your symbols files are useless anywhere but directly on the build server.

Comment: @MrHinsh well the only reason we need the symbols files is to create the NuGet symbols package which sits on the Symbols server. With indexing turned off these pdb work quite nicely and users can debug into the files. We have no other use for the symbols files.

Comment: Without indexed pdb's you will run into issues fairly quickly. You will need identical folder layouts and it will not step through the actual code, but instead the version that you have locally. If they don't match it will not work.

Comment: Hmm OK, so why, when I set "Index Sources" to True, do the dlls and pdbs fail to match?

Comment: Hi openshac, any progress on this? I ran into exactly the same situation. The obj folder on the build machine has the .pdb matching its age, but the "official" one copied by TFS to the Symbol Server folder is one increment "younger". As for your 3rd point, if you are allowed to publish to NuGet directly, you will probably be fine. We want to keep our source code private, so we need this TFS feature to work.

Comment: Hi @Louis, unfortunately we stopped using TFS last year. Sorry.

Comment: Hi @openshac. I was able to step into my code, even with the age property difference, so chkmatch is a bit more sensitive than Visual Studio for this property. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The age discrepancy raised by *chkmatch* is misleading. As discussed [here](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2011/11/11/source-indexing-is-underused-awesomeness/) (bottom comments section)  , it should not prevent Visual Studio from finding the matching Program Database file (PDB) and loading the Symbols.

I have been struggling with this and thought that the age difference was preventing me from stepping through the source code being indexed. There was another issue at hand and it got me on the wrong track. So, a word of caution regarding the age property difference when using *chkmatch* to debug such issues.